Apex Page: Add Terms and Conditions Page AFTER Last Page
I have a document that needs to set a signature block on the last page of a quote document. For this example I am using "only last page" as the signature block footer. The quote document can be one or more pages. The current CSS stylesheet is working as expected, to set the signature block on the last page. However, I also need to include a Terms and Conditions Page AFTER the Last Page. I have tried multiple CSS permutations.
Below is what is currently working to push "only last page" footer on the quote document to the last page.
I am trying to find a solution to add a Terms and Conditions page AFTER the last page. So effectively, a final page to the document without any footer content.
Here is a resource I found for the current design.
Footer on last page while pdf generation by flying saucer
<apex:page controller="CE_QuoteDocumentController" renderAs="pdf"  applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false"><!--renderAs="pdf"-->
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            div.pdf-footer {
                padding-top: 4px;
                position: running(footer);
                
            }
                        
            @page {
                @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer, last);
                }

               @bottom-right {
                   content: "Please turn over";
                }
            }
            
        </style>  
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="pdf-footer">all pages except last</div>

        <div>Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Convallis leo aliquam commodo condimentum; massa pharetra. Dapibus felis tristique aptent ipsum dignissim mi sem taciti praesent. Ultricies ultricies porta non massa sit duis ornare mollis nullam. Faucibus tempus orci integer cursus morbi. Lobortis magna auctor dolor turpis curabitur fames cras. Non nostra consectetur tortor id class suscipit eros. Vehicula sodales vulputate cras hendrerit dolor augue.</div>
         
        <div class="pdf-footer" style="page-break-after:always">only last page <!-- after page break is needed to keep content: please turn over from last page -->

        </div>   
               
    </body>

</apex:page>


